# Is the relation between expansion of a liquid with temperature linear?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, volume

Say I have a liquid with certain volume. If I heat it, will it expand with a constant rate?

$$ \frac{T}{V} = k.$$

It is true for gases, is it also true for liquids? And if yes then: is it true for all liquids?

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet, using your title?

Comment: It is not true for liquids that their expansion is proportional to the change in temperature and in general the cubical expansivity of liquids increases with temperature.  It is also not true for real gases although for some applications one can make assumptions about linearity to a reasonable approximation as is often done for liquids and solids.

Comment: Any assumption on linearity will cover some temperature range to some accuracy. Beware beyond that. All real gases, liquids, and solids are not linear from nanoKelvin temperatures to the surface of the sun. "Linear" expansion coefficients aren't monotonic or even positive for many materials across the entire measured temperature range.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general that liquids expand linearly with the temperature but it might be true for a particular liquid and a particular temperature scale.

Let us say you have mercury. You put that Mercury inside your fridge and after some time you measure its volume and define this Mercury is at $0\, \mathrm{X}$, where $\mathrm{X}$ is the scale you are defining. Then you get this mercury out of the fridge and put it in your (turned on) oven. Some time later you measure the volume and define the mercury is at $100\, \mathrm{X}$. The last step then is to define temperatures at intermediate states, i.e. for intermediate volumes. If you choose a [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), then, by definition, the volume of Mercury will be a linear function of the temperature $\mathrm{X}$.

The point is, if you now get water and measure its temperature in the scale $\mathrm{X}$ it will not be a linear function of the volume because water behaves differently than mercury. Of course you can define a new scale $\mathrm{Y}$ based on water but then the mercury expansion would not be linear.

That is why the absolute scale $\mathrm{K}$ is so important. It can be defined without reference to any particular substance. You can just do it by means of a Carnot engine. However the liquids or even gases in general will not have a linear relation between volume and temperature. It can be linear as a first order approximation at some regimes.

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact, [water has a negative coefficient of expansion from $0 C$ to $4 C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion#Contraction_effects_.28negative_thermal_expansion.29) .